# Unable to connect to AWS EKS cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubectl, amazon-eks

I am configuring an EKS cluster using terraform in a private subnet and trying to access it using a VPN in a public subnet. When I configured it, it works fine but now when I run kubectl get pods or kubectl get svc, it is throwing an error:

`error: exec plugin: invalid apiVersion "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1"`

I don't know why it is happening. Please reply if you the solution.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error: exec plugin: invalid apiVersion "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1" CircleCI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72126048/error-exec-plugin-invalid-apiversion-client-authentication-k8s-io-v1alpha1-c)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's broken with `kubectl` version `1.24`. Downgrade to `1.23.6` will fix the issue for now

```
sudo apt install kubectl=1.23.6-00
```

Comment: Downloading 1.23.7 worked for me. curl -LO "https://dl.k8s.io/v1.23.7/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl"

Answer (score 0):

If you're experiencing this issue with GitHub actions and `kodermax/kubectl-aws-eks`, configure fixed versions for `KUBECTL_VERSION` and `IAM_VERSION` for each deployment step.

```
  - name: deploy to cluster
    uses: kodermax/kubectl-aws-eks@master
    env:
      KUBE_CONFIG_DATA: ${{ secrets.KUBE_CONFIG_DATA_STAGING }}
      ECR_REGISTRY: ${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.registry }}
      ECR_REPOSITORY: my-app
      IMAGE_TAG: ${{ github.sha }
      KUBECTL_VERSION: "v1.23.6"
      IAM_VERSION: "0.5.3"
```